# Numbering nested menu levels

Tags: 7, routes

I've got a custom function which overrides the menu links for a specific menu so I can put my own custom classes into it (see below).

```
function MYTHEME_menu_link__menu_footer_links_1($variables){
    $elements = $variables['elements'];
    $node = menu_get_object(); //Get the node object for page being rendered
    $field_department = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_department'); //Get value of "field_department" field

    //"field_department" exists in this node
    if($field_department !== false){
        $dept_page = is_dept_page($field_department); //Returns true or false

        //Add CSS classes to the anchor tag
        if($dept_page !== false){
            $elements['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = "dept-bg-col";
            $elements['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = "dept-men-col";
        }
    }

    $sub_menu = '';

    if($elements['#below'])
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($elements['#below']);

    $output = l($elements['#title'], $elements['#href'], $elements['#localized_options'] );
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($elements['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

This I believe also calls itself if a specific menu item has any nested menu items too to generate those.

I've also got another function which wraps the list item HTML generated here in a  tag (see below)

```
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__menu_footer_links_1($variables) {
    global $cur_level;
    $cur_level++;

    return '<ul class="menu menu-level-' . $cur_level . ' dept-main-menu list-menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

As you can see this second function adds a menu-level-{number} class but they are being numbered backwards, so the most inner  gets the class menu-level-1 working it's way up the numbers until the top level  gets the highest number.

I'm trying to basically make the numbering go the other way around so the top level gets the class menu-level-1.

I think the reason it is numbering like this is because the first function calls itself & the second function on any nested lists. So the most deeply nested list calls the second function first and as a results gets menu-level-1.

Can anyone thing of a solution to this? Or is there an easier way altogether to get this done?

Comment: Do you just need custom classes for your links?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply but it would be ideal to keep them